# What is the downside of using Monocross for WPF and Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xamarin.ios, monocross

I am thinking...

> Is [Monocross](http://code.google.com/p/monocross/) a good option to use so
>   we could port to the IPad if we were
>   forced to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monocross very nicely follows the kind of pattern enforced by monotouch and monodroid, with a separate presentation layer and application code

According to [MonoCross' own wiki](http://code.google.com/p/monocross/wiki/MonoCross), their intent seems to be to fully support these platforms, *and* windows mobile in the future.

At the time of this writing however, (monoCross 0.3.2) all CRUD related operations are either in development, or not yet started, so there is a good chance you will still run into trouble during your own application development.

The biggest hamper (in my opinion) in porting applications to monotouch, is the lack of databinding support, and monocross has *most* of those implemented at its current release, but not all of them.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that we intend to support the platforms mentioned above, but we will support Windows Phone 7 moving forward, and have deprecated earlier versions of Windows Mobile.

Since the last post on this thread, we have added the concept of view perspectives to help with CRUD operations.  View perspectives are used to enable multiple views for each of your model types, and are represented as a string passed from your controller to the view container to indicate the perspective you wish to provide the user.  This makes it easier to construct and render views for CRUD, or any other, operations.

We are also currently writing a book for Wrox Press that will cover cross-platform development with MonoCross in much more detail.  The book will be available in early 2012.

Scott Olson
MonoCross Project